# Smack android enable xep-0115 cache

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

Hello I'am building an android app using smack, the server support both the xep-0030 and the xep-0115, smack also support them.

What I want to achieve is the ability to cache on the client the server capabilities in order to reduce the number of disco#info performed by the client on login.

Based on the smack documentation what I have done is this:

```
EntityCapsManager entityCapsManager = EntityCapsManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
entityCapsManager.enableEntityCaps();

EntityCapsPersistentCache cache = new SimpleDirectoryPersistentCache(cacheFile);
entityCapsManager.setPersistentCache(cache);
```

but even with this lines of code result in the client always performing the same number of disco#info

there is a solution to my problem or I have to leave with that?

this is an example of my presence:

```
<presence from='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'>
  <c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps'
     hash='sha-1'
     node='http://code.google.com/p/exodus'
     ver='QgayPKawpkPSDYmwT/WM94uAlu0='/>
</presence>
```

Comment: I'd suggest debugging the code to determine why the results are not cached. Note that you need a presence with the caps hash from the remote entity in question for xep115 cache functionality.

Comment: @Flow in the presence the tag "c" with the attribute ver is present

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not see what this statement is supposed to tell me.

Comment: il part of the flow to get mod_caps working, the hash is supposed to be in a tag <c> inside the presence where the ver attribute contains the hash, i have edited the answer to include my presence

Comment: I am sorry, but I may have to repeat my suggestion, as it probably was not clear in the first place: Grab yourself a debugger, attach it to the application and debug why the results are not cached or why the EntityCapsManager does not reduce the number of disco#info lookups.